# AdaptiveTrigger not working on Template10 Shell

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, template10

I'm building my first app for *UWP* platform and I decided to start from the hamburger template included in *Template10*.

What I need to do is something similar to the hamburger menu of the *Groove Music* app included in *Windows 10*, so that clicking on a button of the hamburger opens a `Flyout` to create a new category (like they do for playlists).

Everything works fine and the `Flyout` just opens without issues, the problem shows up when using the app on mobile: the `Flyout` contains a text input that makes the virtual keyboard spawn, moving the `Flyout` outside the screen.

My goal is then to have that Flyout to show on fullscreen when the app is in a narrow visual state, while being shown on the right of the hamburger in the other cases.

Unfortunately it seems that adding the `AdaptiveTrigger`s to the `Shell.xaml` page doesn't work, as nothing happens.

Here's the relevant *XAML* code:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStateGroup">
        <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNarrow">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NarrowMinWidth}" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <!--  TODO: change properties for narrow view  -->
                <Setter Target="CategoryFlyout.Placement"                            
                        Value="Full"/>
                <Setter Target="MyHamburger.HamburgerBackground"
                        Value="Green"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNormal">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NormalMinWidth}" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <!--  TODO: change properties for normal view  -->
                <Setter Target="CategoryFlyout.Placement"                            
                        Value="Right"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateWide">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource WideMinWidth}" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <!--  TODO: change properties for wide view  -->
                <Setter Target="CategoryFlyout.Placement"                            
                        Value="Right"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

<Page.Resources>
    <Flyout x:Key="CategoryFlyout"
            x:Name="CategoryFlyout"
            Placement="Right">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Set category name:"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBox Width="200"
                     Margin="0,5,0,5"       
                     x:Name="CategoryTextBox"
                     utils:ImmediateSourceUpdate.IsEnabled="True"
                     utils:ImmediateSourceUpdate.Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.NewCategoryName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Content="Add"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddCategoryCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Flyout>
</Page.Resources>
```

As you can see there's a `<Setter Target="MyHamburger.HamburgerBackground" Value="Green"/>` line used to see if the issue could be related to the `Flyout` itself, but even this line doesn't work (I'd expect the background fo the hamburger button to be green but it doesn't change from default).

*Tempate10*'s model includes a *MainPage.xaml* which prints the current visual state so I'm sure that I'm using the correct one to set the `Flyout`, still I have no results.
Nothing happens, not even errors in the debug console.

I also tried inserting the `AdaptiveTrigger`s inside the `HamburgerMenu` but even this didn't work.

Do you have any ideas on why is this failing?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Template 10 issue. The Flyout control is not intended to be used on Mobile. Please use ContentDialog or a custom Popup. It's not ideal, I know; but I am not the author of the entire XAML platform, just Template 10. :)

> Their reasoning, by the way, has to do with this line of thinking: exactly how should a Flyout look on the Phone?

In all reality, if this is for settings or something, just create a new page.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment and for what you did with Tempate10 :) BTW my issue is not only related to `Flyout` itself. As you can see I have a `Setter` in `VisualStateNarrow` which should change hamburger button's background but it doesn't work. Seems like `AdaptiveTrigger`'s are not fired from `Shell.xaml` page but this is just a random guess.